# Why can't I navigate when using a WebViewClient in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I've created an Activity into which a website launches. 
In the app, i've set the AppTheme so that it is Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar 
so the action bar isn't displayed on any of the activity layouts.

This is the webview layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

The webpage loads fine. But there are no navigation properties and I also would like to be able to "cancel" the WebView and go back to the parent activity.

I tried to implement some of the code I found on the android dev pages, specifically having the webpage open up in a WebView and not in a browser eg. chrome.

```
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html
```

Activity;

```
public class WebActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String webAddress;
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webAddress = getIntent().getStringExtra("WEB_ADDRESS");
        myWebView.loadUrl(webAddress);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

But I can't see any navigation properties and I'm also unsure how to cancel the activity because I have removed the app bar as the theme.

Comment: I recommend you using this library which is so perfect for what you are looking for https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have toolbar because webview does not provide any navigation button. You can have something like this in your layout and set the back button action with `onBackPressed`. You need to override onBackPressed and check if your webview `canGoBack()`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:contentInsetStart="5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/backBtn"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backBtn"
                    android:text="Your title"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Alternatively, you also can use chrome custom tabs (available for Jellybean onwards). The implementation is quite straightforward. Refer here for [implementation guide](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) of Chrome Custom Tabs

Comment: But I don't want Chrome to open. I want the user to navigate from within my app.

Answer (score 1):

I guess with "navigation properties" you mean the browser chrome, i.e. the usual back and forward buttons, the refresh/cancel button and the URL bar. These are not available in the WebView.

You could implement UI widgets that call the appropriate methods like `WebView.goBack()` or `WebView.loadUrl()` etc. But if you need that it would probably be better to invoke a real browser via intent.

Concerning "canceling" the WebView: You could override the activity's `onBackPressed` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack())
        webView.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The effect is that pressing the back button on your device goes back in browser history until it reaches the initial web page. Then it destroys the activity as usual and returns to the parent activity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WebView haven't navigation properties but you can handle `goBack`, `goForward` and `reload`.

For `goBack`

```
 if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
      myWebView.goBack();
 }
```

For `goForward`

```
 if (myWebView.canGoForward()) {
      myWebView.goForward();
 }
```

For `reload`

```
 myWebView.reload();
```